# What were the complaints filed under "other" in the survey data?

Tags: support, status-completed, blog, community, stack-overflow-developer-survey

In the latest blog post, [The Loop #2: Understanding Site Satisfaction, Summer 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/), this graphic is included:

[image: transcription below]

> **Coded responses to "What do you find most frustrating or unappealing about using Stack Overflow?"**
>
> Unwelcoming community 10.6%
> Design 9.8%
> Artifact quality 9.7%
> Barrier to participation 8.3%
> Discovery 8.0%
> Overmoderation 7.1%
> Voting 5.1%
> Question quality 4.2%
> Timely answers 3.5%
> Other 3.2%
> Comments 2.2%
> Onboarding 2.1%
> Social friction 1.8%
> Subjective content 0.8%
> Mobile app/site 0.6%
> Welcoming backlash 0.5%
> Job quality 0.4%
> Review queues 0.3%

One of the statistics is marked "other", comprising 3.2% of responses.

What are some of the complaints filed under "other"? Can we get some more of the actual data - presumably those responses that were less than 0.3% of the responses - presented here? It'd be interesting know what issues people are encountering, even in the very small percentages.

Comment: (Only 10 % of respondents were disgruntled users taking this opportunity to vent? Big success!) If you mean free-form answers, these are very hard to release: they can easily identify persons or otherwise be inappropriate. Quite often, a word cloud is the best one can manage to publish out of them within a short timeline.

Comment: Observation by SR: in order for Other to be a meaningful category at 3.2%, it would have to comprise of at least 10 different subcategories, none of which raise above 0.3% (that's how much review queues got), and none of which can be combined into a single category

Comment: ... And what happened to the other 20% of responses that weren't filed under Other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From our UX researcher who was involved with coding the survey responses:

> We coded responses as Other for miscellaneous issues that were not captured in the other coding categories. Some examples of topics mentioned in the Other category are ads, data policy, and feature requests.
>
> Below are sample responses in the Other category:
>
> - *There is no possibility for a video chat or simply a voice chat in order to speed up and understanding questions...*
> - *“Hot Network Questions” section constantly distracts me from my work. Please make it optional.*
> - *The ads*
> - *Data policy*
> - *It lacks good wikis, although it is not meant to have them but still*
> - *Persistent tracking for the purpose of targeted ads*
> - *Unfair points subtraction*
> - *Not easy to check the code for Mobile Development*