# "The Loop #2" contains inaccessible images with no transcription

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, blog, accessibility

The latest blog post, "[The Loop #2: Understanding Site Satisfaction, Summer 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019)", contains a graph showing percentages of responses to the site satisfaction survey:

> [image: transcription below]
>
> **Coded responses to "What do you find most frustrating or unappealing about using Stack Overflow?"**
>
> Unwelcoming community 10.6%
> Design 9.8%
> Artifact quality 9.7%
> Barrier to participation 8.3%
> Discovery 8.0%
> Overmoderation 7.1%
> Voting 5.1%
> Question quality 4.2%
> Timely answers 3.5%
> Other 3.2%
> Comments 2.2%
> Onboarding 2.1%
> Social friction 1.8%
> Subjective content 0.8%
> Mobile app/site 0.6%
> Welcoming backlash 0.5%
> Job quality 0.4%
> Review queues 0.3%

However, if one cannot see images - such as someone using a screen reader, or has images disabled - the information contained on the chart is inaccessible.

When someone has images disabled, all that shows up is a blank space where the image is placed in the blog post:

> [image: screenshot of blog post, showing white blank spot in space of image]

...showing that there is no alt text for this image.

However, in the meta post [Can we have the dataset for the loop #2?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342777/294691), for example, (and, uh, in this post above,) the image is included along with a textual transcription:

> [image: screenshot showing "transcription below" where the image did not show, and a text transcription of the graph underneath]

**Could you please include text descriptions and alt text of images in official communications and blog posts?**

Comment: Just wanted to add a Thank You for asking this.

Comment: No promises cause I haven't heard back yet, but I did pass this along internally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

We added the contents of the chart into the `alt` text on the image. Please let me know if there's anything else we can update to make the post more accessible.