# Revision history behaves strangely when there is only an edit in Markdown

Tags: bug, edits, markdown, revisions-list

I was trying to see what was changed from revision 1 to revision 2 of this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382394/do-we-really-need-new-contributor-messages-for-stack-exchange-staff) and it appeared that nothing changed in the side-by-side view:

[image: Screenshot of revision history showing revision 2 in side-by-side view without any content beneath that.]

I switched to the side-by-side Markdown view and the view stayed the same.

[image: Screenshot of revision history showing revision 2 in side-by-side Markdown view without any content beneath that.]

I brought this up in chat, and [others](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9310635#9310635) were able to see that there in fact was a difference in side-by-side Markdown, where only part of the Markdown was changed.

I tried switching back and forth between side-by-side and side-by-side Markdown but nothing happened. Refreshing the page also didn't save my preference to see the side-by-side Markdown view.

I then visited a random question's revision history, switched to side-by-side Markdown there, and went back to this question's revision history to be finally shown the changes made in Markdown:

[image: Review history in side-by-side Markdown view showing the change in placement of a hyperlink from inline to footnotes]

**In conclusion:** Somehow the revision history gets tricked into not seeing the changes in a revision, when there are only changes in Markdown, and the view on the revision history page is not in side-by-side Markdown. At the same time switching between views once this occurs is broken.

This has been going on since at least [the start of this month](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9291868#9291868).